# Count returning incorrect result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a count query which isn't working, as expected. 
The query is below and it returns three columns - DeparmtmentName, CategoryName and NumberOfCats.

The NumberOfCats column should show the number of Categories in a given Department.

So with the table below, the NumberOfCats column should have the number 4 in each row, instead of 1, because the Bakey Department has 4 Categories, in this case.

Does anyone know how I can amend the code, so it returns the right result, please?

[image]

```
SELECT 
        DepartmentName,
        CategoryName,       
        COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryName) as NumberOfCats
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
GROUP BY 
        DepartmentName,
        CategoryName
ORDER BY DepartmentName;
```

Comment: If you have different levels of aggregation, the most common way is to use different queries to compute and then join them, like Honey's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a window function will take care of these pretty easily:

```
SELECT 
        DepartmentName,
        CategoryName,       
        COUNT( CategoryName) OVER(Partition by DepartmentName) as NumberOfCats
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
group by DepartmentName,
        CategoryName
```

Comment: Only if you don't have duplicates.

Comment: That is correct, but as you will notice that is the same issue with every answer on this thread.  Since the OP never mentioned that I would assume there is not

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you JMabee!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to seperate the count from the rest:

```
SELECT 
        T1.DepartmentName,
        T1.CategoryName,       
        AG.NumberOfCats
FROM    v_EnterpriseStructure T1
INNER JOIN (
                SELECT  DepartmentName,
                COUNT(DISTINCT CategoryName) as NumberOfCats
                FROM    v_EnterpriseStructure
                GROUP BY DepartmentName
            ) AS AG
        ON AG.DepartmentName = T1.DepartmentName
ORDER BY DepartmentName;
```

You may need to add a `DISTINCT`

Comment: Hi HoneyBadger - thanks for posting this! It gives the correct result - but it duplicates them, as you predicted. Do you know where I should add the distinct clause in the query in order to prevent the duplicates? Also, I don't understand what the T1 and AF bits meant in the code - it still worked with them, but if you could clarify what they mean, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mr2017 T1 is a placeholder table name. AG stands for Aggregate I guess, it's the name of the "join table" that is aggregated by the select in the join. When making queries where tables join on themselves etc.. you usually give them names.

Comment: @Mr2017...As Tschallacka explained, T1 and AG are aliases (indeed I intended AG to stand for Aggregate, its a usual alias I use in situations like this). The `DISTINCT` you should place right after the `SELECT`, so `SELECT DISTINCT T1.DepartmentName ...`

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One option, using `COUNT()` as an analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentName) cnt
    FROM v_EnterpriseStructure
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    DepartmentName,
    CategoryName,       
    cnt AS NumberOfCats
FROM cte
ORDER BY DepartmentName;
```

Comment: Sorry had a typo in there.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for posting this. However, when I run this code, it returns over 1,000 records for the number of Categories, which is too high. The answer posted by HoneyBadger gives the correct result... so I'm not sure what needs to be changed with the code here?

Answer (score 1):

By adding a subquery to your query you can get the data you need. If your table is < 100.000 this should run without issues. if it's larger you might wish to consider altering your data structures.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d30e1/1

The create statement.

```
create table v_EnterpriseStructure (DepartmentName nvarchar(50), CategoryName nvarchar(50)) 
CREATE INDEX IX_DepartmentName
ON v_EnterpriseStructure(DepartmentName);
insert into v_EnterpriseStructure VALUES 
('BAKERY', 'Bread'),('BAKERY', 'Cakes'),('BAKERY', 'Scones'),('BAKERY', 'Croissants'),
('BAR', 'Beer'),('BAR', 'Cola'),
('Storage', 'MrProper'),('Storage', 'MrProper');
insert into v_EnterpriseStructure select * from v_EnterpriseStructure;
insert into v_EnterpriseStructure select * from v_EnterpriseStructure;
insert into v_EnterpriseStructure select * from v_EnterpriseStructure;
insert into v_EnterpriseStructure select * from v_EnterpriseStructure;
insert into v_EnterpriseStructure select * from v_EnterpriseStructure;
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
        DepartmentName,
        CategoryName,       
        (select 
            COUNT(distinct CategoryName) from v_EnterpriseStructure as v2 
            where v1.DepartmentName = v2.DepartmentName

        ) as NumberOfCats
FROM v_EnterpriseStructure as v1
group by DepartmentName,
         CategoryName
ORDER BY DepartmentName;
```

Comment: @Mr2017 I modified my answer. This might be what you're looking for? a count of different categories within the DepartmentName?

Comment: Hi Tschallacka, thanks for posting this. When I run it, however, I get the error message shown here: Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
View or function 'v_EnterpriseStructure' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.
Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
View or function 'v_EnterpriseStructure' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Also, there are dozens of Categories across the various Departments. Would I have to insert all the Category names into the query, as you've done above? I'd like to run the query automatically.

Comment: @Mr2017 The query above is just what I inserted in the SQL fiddle. I added the Create table here, so that in the future, if someone comes and the SQL fiddle link doesn't work anymore, they can still run the code/make a new SQL fiddle. Please use the code from the select statement.  I edited my answer to make it clearer which to use.

Comment: Ok, thanks Tschallacka. I've used the code from the query above and it works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @Mr2017 You're new to Stack Overflow. To indicate an answer has solved your problem you can click the checkmark icon under the upvote/downvote arrows to indicate to others that it solved your problem

Comment: Ok, - yes, I did that for all the answers that worked, above. Are you not able to see them on your end?

Comment: @Mr2017 No, I only see upvotes. Not an accepted mark at any of the answers on this question. There's no green check to be seen.

Comment: Ok, I've marked one of the with the checkmark. I'd like to do this for all of them.  However, it only lets you mark one answer with the checkmark?

Comment: @Mr2017 Yes. The checkmark is for the answer that solved your problem. Although there may be more usuable solutions, the one that solved your problem the best/ the one you used should be indicated with the checkmark as the proper answer. Other viable answers can stand with an upvote.